# Redirection loop with WordPress on a VPS

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, .htaccess, vps, wordpress

I have setup on a VPS a WordPress and DNS to redirect a domain name to my server. But I have trouble to hide the IP of the server. In fact when I am redirected from my domain name to the server, the URL changes from `www.example.com/wordpress` to `XXXXXX/wordpress` (`XXXXXX` is the IP address).

So I tried to change the Site URL in the settings for the domain name. However I got stuck in a loop between the server and the domain name or itself. In the settings I changed it to `http://www.example.com/wordpress` instead of `http://XXXXXX/wordpress`

Here is my configuration for the VirtualHost : `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName  example
   ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
<Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here my `.htaccess` `/var/www/wordpress/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in my log we can see that I have some internal redirections

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.html -> index.html
applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri 'index.html'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.html -> index.html
applying pattern '.' to uri 'index.html'
rewrite 'index.html' -> '/wordpress/index.php'
trying to replace prefix /var/www/wordpress/ with /wordpress/
internal redirect with /wordpress/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.cgi -> index.cgi
applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri 'index.cgi'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.cgi -> index.cgi
applying pattern '.' to uri 'index.cgi'
rewrite 'index.cgi' -> '/wordpress/index.php'
trying to replace prefix /var/www/wordpress/ with /wordpress/
internal redirect with /wordpress/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.pl -> index.pl
applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri 'index.pl'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.pl -> index.pl
applying pattern '.' to uri 'index.pl'
rewrite 'index.pl' -> '/wordpress/index.php'
trying to replace prefix /var/www/wordpress/ with /wordpress/
internal redirect with /wordpress/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What is your "wordpress address" set to in settings? When does the URL change from the domain name to the IP address, when you first connect or when you click? If it's when you first connect please do a curl showing headers (-i I think) to show the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution, I called the technical support of my DNS provider and we found out that I had misconfigured it. To help people who could have the same problem here it is.

My DNS provider is 1&1 and I did an http redirection to my ip and it was wrong. The proper way is to set the domain name as a web component and to set in the DNS parameter an A record to the ip address of the server.

I made this mistake because I thought that the web component was for website made by 1&1's website builder.

Thank's for your reply user378702

Answer (score 0):

You can change DocumentRoot to /var/www/wordpress/

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress/
```


Edited: 
If you want hide server IP you can use new server as proxy with nginx and nginx redirect to apache server, and dns configure to proxy server .

Comment: Although this probably wouldn't do anything to "hide the IP of the server". (?)

Comment: sorry my mistake the wrong read on - I have edited my post.

Comment: Why are you answering an apache question with nginx?